# SQL composite properties and redundancy

Tags: sql, postgresql

Premise: I am new to SQL and databases.

What I do not understand is: are composite properties considered redundant if all the components to construct them are stored in other properties in the database? If yes, can I still use them to avoid expensive queries, even though this means adding some redundancy in the database?

As an example: imagine an online store where users can buy and sell items. The tables are:

- `user(unique_id, name, money, ...)`
- `transaction(seller_id, buyer_id, item_id, ...)`
- `item(unique_id, price, ...)`

Now, to find the profits a user has made I sum the price of all the items the user has sold and remove from it the price of all the products the user has bought.
In pseudocode:

`profits = SUM(sales) - SUM(purchases)`

The problem I see with this query is that it gets slower as the number of transactions the user has made gets bigger.

To speed things up I could simply add to the `user` table a property `profits` which gets updated each time the user makes a transaction. It would be faster than summing and subtracting all the transactions all the time, but it looks like it introduces some redundancy in the database since `profits` is a composite value. Should I bother about?

Comment: Which dbms are you working with? (Some of them have "calculated" columns.)

Comment: Before post the answer, could you please clarify. Do you complain about performance (then I'd recommend you use indexes) or denormalization (adding extra columns)?

Comment: @jarlh I am working with PostgreSQL

Comment: @Dewfy I am trying to understand whether storing the result of a function in a column is considered redundancy if I have all the data needed to obtain that result in another table of the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depend on what you need. And the compromise you are willing to make. You always can try both solution it and see if you get any improvement or not.

- Your original query is standard in db we call it normalized database. Adding index on related field help a lot and will solve all your performance issue.
- `profits` is what we call calculated field.

  - Pros: will speed `select` statement
  - Cons: Need more storage (minimal in this case), will slow `insert/update`

For your case, first solution is ok, db are build to handle tables with those configuration with millions rows without problem.

But for example in this case, where `distance` need `sin`, `cos` and `radians`.

```
( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(' . $location_lat . '))' .
                '* cos( radians( s.latitude ) )' .
                '* cos( radians( s.longitude )' .
                '- radians(' . $location_lng . ') )' .
                '+ sin( radians(' . $location_lat . ') )' .
                '* sin( radians( s.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'
```

You get major perfomance improvement in `selects` if calculate that `distance` once because those functions are very slow.